# How to prevent the need to sign in to accounts on Mac

Tags: macos, mac, notifications, system-settings, accounts

My Mac is connected to my Google (Gmail) and Microsoft (Outlook) accounts.
Every few days (once or twice a week) I have notifications that tell me to re-sign-in to these accounts;

1. In most of the times, the System Preferences window pops up but no signing-in is actually needed, so I close it.
2. In The other times in which signing-in is needed when the window pops up, all services work fine even when I dismiss it, so signing in is not *actually* necessary.

I would like to fix this:

- To not have redundant notifications (§1).
- To not have to sign in again and again to an account I already signed-in to (both §1 & §2).
- Automatically dismissing/hiding/preventing the notifications themselves is also okay, as services are working anyway (see §2).

Comment: Is this about accounts used in Mail only, or about Google Drive/OneDrive as well?

Comment: Do you connect to these services on another computers or mobile devices?

Comment: Have you tried removing the accounts and adding them back? Sometimes macOS may think that an account change happened and resetting the connection can help.